# Как создать ссылку навигации по разделам?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Приложение написано на react, роутинг через react touter, нужно в шапке страницы сделать элемент навигации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Некоторые элементы пути должны формироваться динамически, можно просто подставлять, можно брать из URL страницы, на которой находимся. Элементы должны быть кликабельными ссылками на страницы.

Как это лучше реализовать, может быть есть готовые решения или нужно изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Как вариант, иметь некий массив "хлебных крошек", вот его и выводить. Сам массив можно хранить в некоем стейте, иметь возможность добавлять и удалять "крошки"...

Comment: Пытался реализовать подобным образом, возникает сложность при создании этого массива, когда я перехожу на страницу по ссылке, то есть путь не формируется в процессе последовательного перехода по разделам.

Comment: Если на страницу попал "из вне" - на странице можно проверить этот стейт с ХК. Если стейт пустой - заполнить его стейтом "по умолчанию" для этой страницы... Т.е. каждая страница может иметь некие ХК "по умолчанию".